# SlidingDrawer - Resize view instead of overlap

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

When I drag the handle to bring the content of `SlidingDrawer` on screen (it occupies 1/3 of the screen), it will overlap the main view. I want the main view to be always visible and resize it when the `SlidingDrawer` is open. It is possible to configure in xml file to resize the main view when `SlidingDrawer` is open, or I have to make it programmatically using `setOnDrawerOpenListener`?

Answer (score 4):

SlidingDrawer doesn't know about the underlying views and will not resize them. You will need to create a custom component to do this.

Comment: I it is possible to resize the main view with setLayoutParams when onDrawerClosed or onDrawerOpend is fired...